# Filter blob data in Copy Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a copy Activity that copies data from Blob to Azure Data Lake.  The Blob is populated by an Azure function with an event hub trigger. Blob files are appended with UNIX timestamp which is the event enqueued time in the event hub. Azure data factory is triggered every hour to merge the files and move them over to Data lake.

[image]

Inside the source dataset I have filters by Last Modified date in UTC time out of the box.  I can use this but it limits me to use Last modified date in the blob.  I want to use my own date filters and decide where I want to apply these filters.  Is this possible in Data factory?  If yes, can you please point me in the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ADF in any case,the only idea that came to my mind is using combination of [Look Up Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) ,[ForEach Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) and [Filter Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-filter-activity).Maybe it is kind of complex.

1.Use Look up to retrieve the data from the blob file.

2.Use ForEach Activity to loop the result and set your data time filters.

3.Inside the ForEach Activity, do the copy task.

Please refer to this [blog](http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/matthow/post/Using-Lookup-Execute-Pipeline-and-For-Each-Activity-in-Azure-Data-Factory-V2) to get some clues.

Reviewing your descriptions of all the tasks you did now, I suggest you getting an idea of [Azure Stream Analytics Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/). No matter the data source is Event Hub or Azure Blob Storage, ASA supports them as [input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-add-inputs). And it supports ADL as [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs#azure-data-lake-store).

You could create a job to configure input and output,then use popular [SQL language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/stream-analytics-query-language-reference?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) to filter your data however you want.Such as [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/where-azure-stream-analytics) operator or [DataTime Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/date-and-time-functions-azure-stream-analytics).

Comment: Hey thank for the suggestion.  I implemented this in ADF but used a lot of lookups, foreach and stored proc activities.